# SSRS Consuming a Single Core

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I have production SQL Server machine with 10 separate instances on it: The last instance that was added included an install of SSRS. Since that time I've seen high CPU usage on a random single core (80% or higher), I believe this is related to SSRS (it consistently has the a higher CPU usage than anything on the server, around 2-3%). I'm not having any luck tracking down what exactly it is doing hour after hour, day after day. It's doesn't grow to take over the all the machine resources but I like to figure out what exactly it's doing so I can decide whether I should actually be worried about or not...

EDIT [2015-5-12]: I've been able to confirm that it is indeed the SQL 2012 SSRS process that is the source of the extra CPU load and we are currently running perfmon and waiting for it to re-occur.

Comment: Are any of your instances configured not to use parallel query execution?

Comment: 2 out of 10 but neither are associated with either SSRS installation (1 is Sharepoint 2013 and the other is vendor requirement for their back end). Wouldn't parallelism be reflected in CPU usage of the SQLServr.exe process rather than ReportingServicesService.exe?

Comment: If you are trying to take a closer look at the process, why don't you run something like [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)? I believe you can set cpu affinity with it if you want and you can get more details on what's happening.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at your logs (<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.<InstanceName>\Reporting Services\LogFiles) to see if you have any exceptions. 2008 had some issues  with .Net so you could need [this hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971988/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0).  Also if this is in SharePoint Integrated mode, [that might be the source of your woes](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/1/25/whats-up-with-the-slow-ssrs-r2-rendering-in-sharepoint-2010.html).  If it isn't a problem, I wouldn't worry too much about it personally.